# ESLint - Prefer Export Default to Module.Exports

Tags: javascript, styles, eslint

I was wondering if an ESLint rule exists, or how to make one, that does the following:

Allows exports only in the form `export default foo` and not in the form `module.exports = foo`

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no core rules that can do this, but the following plugin rule might be what you are looking for:

https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-commonjs.md

It will report any usage of CommonJS-style modules:

**Invalid**:

```
/*eslint no-commonjs: "error"*/
module.exports = foo;
```

**Valid**:

```
/*eslint no-commonjs: "error"*/
export default foo;
```

Answer (score 3):

module.exports is specific to Node.
so add it to the env, like below

```
env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    es2021: true,
},
```